# synology ds212j slow transfer speed

Tags: file-transfer, synology

I have `Synology DS212j` and I'm getting *REALLY* slow transfer speed, about ~10MB/s.

I used following knowledge base in order to troubleshoot it:

[What should I do if file transfers are slow? - FAQ - Synology - Network Attached Storage (NAS)](https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/faq/586)

1. Network Status - `1000 Mbps, Full duplex, MTU 1500`
2. Storage Manager - no problem
3. My computer's CPU - no problem.

Please advise.

Comment: Lots of little files will copy a lot more slowly than fewer large files. Are you using SMB, HTTP, or something else? SMB will always be slower than something like HTTP. I've seen a huge difference in speed if I upload files through the HTTP GUI vs using a mounted SMB on my own Synology NAS.

Comment: Check the Ethernet cable, it might be CAT5, thus capping you at about 12.5 MB/s.

Comment: I'm using `CAT5E` Ethernet cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"slow transfer speed" - was due to enabled encryption, as soon as I disabled encryption speed went up substantially.

Comment: For future reference, was SMB encryption enabled, or shared folder encryption? What exactly did you disable?

Comment: @wouter I believe it was `Shared Folder`, I don't think "SMB encryption" even exists)